# Aligning the <li></li> to the navbar menu collection

Tags: html, css

I'm playing with this code now and trying to learn something in this, I have trying to align my `<li></li>` to collection in header menu but suddenly I failed a lot. Can someone explain me the solution on this?

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mega-dropdown', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #c42027;
}
h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  width: 130px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  border-right: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 17px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 285px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 19px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 283px;
  z-index: 8;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #222;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #000000;
  white-space: normal;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff3546;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #ff3546;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="images/logo/conlins logo.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">
            <li class="col-sm-4">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dresses</li>
                <li><a href="#">Unique Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Image Responsive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newsletter Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Four columns</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Tops</li>
                <li><a href="#">Good Typography</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-4">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Jackets</li>
                <li><a href="#">Easy to customize</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Glyphicons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Pants</li>
                <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-4">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:AlertIt();">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
        <li>
          <div class="social_media">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/conlinscoffee/">
              <img src="images/social_media/facebook.png" height="20px" width="auto">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/conlinscoffee">
              <img src="images/social_media/twitter.png" height="20px" width="auto">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="images/social_media/instagram.png" height="20px" width="auto">
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you outline what you want the layout to look like (e.g. by providing a specific description or sketch)?

Comment: i can't align my li tags to collection in header it aligns under

Comment: @SicarioSeham Can you show us, where it fails? Coz we can't see it. You need to show us something that looks and fails. If you try running the snippet, it will show something basic, which is not we need.

Comment: here sir this is the screenshot http://i63.tinypic.com/2k4so7.png , i want it to be perfect align as header menu

Comment: @SicarioSeham if you add the `BootstrapCDN` to your snippet, you'll see that they are aligned and not as your screenshot depicts. Perhaps you have overwriting CSS that we are not privy of.

Comment: @SicarioSeham You say, you want the events, etc. to come next to the Collection?

Comment: @SicarioSeham the `bootstrap.min.js` is dependent on `jquery.min.js`. Place jQuery first.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar yes collection then events

Comment: @SicarioSeham The image is taken on the desktop, on the web, and is horizontally aligned. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe try making the Li the same line height as it's siblings? Find out the parenting element's height and set the line-height of the container to that

Comment: @PraveenKumar http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281316/fixing-wrong-code-in-peoples-questions

Comment: @Rob I didn't *fix* OP's code. Just added the snippet with the same issue, but working one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right, the class `mega-dropdown` is what is making it take full width. So if you take away that class, it works. Or just remove the `width: 100%`.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mega-dropdown', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #c42027;
}
h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
}
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  width: 130px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
  /* width: 100%; */
}
.mega-dropdown-menu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  border-right: 17px solid transparent;
  border-left: 17px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 285px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 17px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 19px solid transparent;
  border-left: 19px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 283px;
  z-index: 8;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #222;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #000000;
  white-space: normal;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff3546;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  color: #ff3546;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="images/logo/conlins logo.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu row">
            <li class="col-sm-4">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dresses</li>
                <li><a href="#">Unique Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Image Responsive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Newsletter Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Four columns</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Tops</li>
                <li><a href="#">Good Typography</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-4">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Jackets</li>
                <li><a href="#">Easy to customize</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Glyphicons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Pants</li>
                <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-4">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Accessories</li>
                <li><a href="#">Default Navbar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lovely Fonts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Responsive Dropdown </a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Newsletter</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:AlertIt();">Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
        <li>
          <div class="social_media">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/conlinscoffee/">
              <img src="images/social_media/facebook.png" height="20px" width="auto">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/conlinscoffee">
              <img src="images/social_media/twitter.png" height="20px" width="auto">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="images/social_media/instagram.png" height="20px" width="auto">
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]